# PHP/JQUERY Defining an included page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a website where pages are loaded dynamically inside of a DIV container using JQUERY.

```
            $("div#container div.content div.main").load(siteLink+"/"+newloadVal);
```

It works great, however, I am looking for a way to stop visitors from accessing these included pages THROUGH their actual weblinks such as site.com/pagelink.php.

My main question is, is there a way to do a similar PHP define("THROUGHJS,true); using Javascript, so if the visitor accesses the included page through its actual link, it will redirect to an error page?

Is there an easy way to do this, mainly through JUST PHP?

---

I have not attempted this, but is this possible:

In the parent page, have DEFINE("mainpage",true),

then in the dynamically loaded page, have:

```
if(defined("mainpage")){
...}
else { exit; } // Show an error?\
```

I am not sure if this is possible as the dynamic page is not being loaded via PHP, therefore the defined function in the parent page will not "exist" to the dynamic page?

Thanks for any help in advance. (Sorry if this may seem confusing) :P

Comment: It is not possible. Anything your browser can access (including through JavaScript), you can access manually as well. You can require a session to be present, which will prevent users from accessing your link directly if they haven't gone through the process that creates it; but if they have, they can use direct links. If that is what you meant, use `start_session` and `$_SESSION` to implement it.

Comment: Not necessarily true @Amadan, Codeigniter makes use of this very principal.

Comment: @Amadan That's a good idea! It should fix the issue somewhat, however it will stop create problems as no one should be able to access ANY of the direct links. All direct links will have been "stripped down" from their CSS, etc because it will all have been included via the parent page.

Comment: Use a MVC framework - like CI that @Zarazthuztra recommended.

Comment: It's not 100% the same as what OP is asking, but it's effectively the same. Plus, CI has a nifty feature that lets you detect if the call was from an AJAX script or not.

Comment: could also send post data such as a csrf token with each ajax request...and if no post variable in http request do a redirect

Answer (score 1):

A possible semi-solution:
Generate a unique key for a user's session and pass it to all requests to the additional pages.
For each request of an additional page through jquery, include this key as a query parameter (or as post data). When the required page is loaded, check if the key matches the user's session. If not, display an error.
Something like this:

`$("...").load(siteLink + "/" + newloadVal + "?key=<?php echo $session_key ?>");`

This will not actually prevent users from directly accessing your pages, but it will require them to know a valid key. For this the (average user) will have to visit the main page, look at the source, find the key, etc.

Comment: That's a pretty good idea. I've been looking around for some solutions to my problem, and this seems like the best so far. The big problem is that darn direct access! :P

Comment: I'm thinking of using AJAX however, that way I can use HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH to help stop people from viewing the page directly.
The only problem I can see with this is that the pages may take a little longer to load as it must send the AJAX request.

Comment: Also good. Just note that the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header, as with all http headers, is easy to fake. I would still suggest to use something (like my above solution) that would be unique to the session. You can use a combination of both.

Comment: Thanks :)
I'm going to use the PHP header and also do a session key as well for maximum safety :P

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I ended up going with an AJAX request, that way I can use request headers to determine if the page was loaded using AJAX or not.

Thanks for all your help guys :)